# Uncaught TypeError Error with a GET XHR script. Cannot read property 'abort' of undefined

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

The script below should be sending an XMLHttpRequest, but is throwing the `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'abort' of undefined` in console when it's ran. This is for a homework assignment and I have triple checked to make sure this is the code that they are telling me to run... I cannot find any errors. But regardless, I just want this to work.

The most I can tell is that the variable 'httpRequest' is being registered as undefined... maybe it's in the function that get's assigned to it? I'm lost and don't know how to fix it.

```
// global variables
var selectedCity = "Tucson, AZ";
var httpRequest = false;
var weatherReport;

function getRequestObject() { // Possible function responsible for error?
  try {
    httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  catch (requestError) {
    document.querySelector("p.error").innerHTML = "Forecast not supported by your browser.";
    document.querySelector("p.error").style.display = "block";
    return false;
  }
}

function getWeather(evt) {
   var latitude;
   var longitude;
   if (evt.type !== "load") {
      if (evt.target) {
         selectedCity = evt.target.innerHTML;
      } else if (evt.srcElement) {
         selectedCity = evt.srcElement.innerHTML;
      }
   }
   if (selectedCity === "Tucson, AZ") {
      latitude = 37.7577;
      longitude = -122.4376;
   } else if (selectedCity === "Chicago, IL") {
      latitude = 41.8337329;
      longitude = -87.7321555;
   } else if (selectedCity === "Montreal, QC") {
      latitude = 45.5601062;
      longitude = -73.7120832;
   }
   if (!httpRequest) {
     httpRequest = getRequestObject();
   }
   httpRequest.abort(); // Where the error is thrown...
   httpRequest.open("get","solar.php?" + "lat=" + latitude + "&lng=" + longitude, true);
   httpRequest.send(null);
   httpRequest.onreadystatechange = fillWeather;
}

function fillWeather() {
  if(httpRequest.readyState === 4 && httpRequest.status === 200) {
    weatherReport = JSON.parse(httpRequest.responseText);
  }
}

var locations = document.querySelectorAll("section ul li");
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
   if (locations[i].addEventListener) {
      locations[i].addEventListener("click", getWeather, false);
   } else if (locations[i].attachEvent) {
      locations[i].attachEvent("onclick", getWeather);
   }
}
if (window.addEventListener) {
   window.addEventListener("load", getWeather, false);
} else if (window.attachEvent) {
   window.attachEvent("onload", getWeather);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to `return httpRequest` in `getRequestObject()`, so `httpRequest = getRequestObject()` sets it to undefined.